# FreeRadius : PAM and EAP-TTLS/PEAP

Tags: freeradius, pam

I have a FreeRadius server set up that authenticates users through the PAM (SSSD for AD authentication + MFA via Google Authenticator).

It works well but when I configured it on my firewall I received a message like that :

When authenticating user xxx from 'ip from domain controller', a less secure authentication method PAP is used. Please migrate to PEAP or EAP-TTLS.

I don't understand what this message exactly means. How can I secure the info between my FW/SSH console and the radius server and between the radius server and the domain controller ?

Can I still use PAM with PEAP/EAP-TTLS ? Is it just a mean to secure the network transaction or is it an authentication model ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The pam_radius plugin always uses pap, and the radius client with pam does not exist with PEAP/EAP-TTLS/EAP-TLS. PAP is less secure because it displays password in plain text. For security reasons you can either have a VPN which may need external hardware or have a TLS proxy like stunnel or nginx at the PAM -radius client and protect the radius packets with TLS. I will go for 2nd option as it is free and freeradius server can be configured to use radsec connection, but ofcourse you will now manage the certificates